# Get false only if all users have Status == 1 (asp.net mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My model has this property

```
public bool AllInactive
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (UserRow ur in Users)
            {
                if (ur.Status == 1) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

but I need to get false only if **all** users have `Status == 1`.
How should I change my code to get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use LINQ as it's the clearest way to express your intent:-

```
public bool AllInactive
{
  get { return !Users.All(x => x.Status == 1); }
}
```

or if you prefer:-

```
public bool AllInactive
{
  get { return Users.Any(x => x.Status != 1); }
}
```

You'll need to include `System.Linq` in your usings if it's not included already.

Comment: Note: OP wrote `I need to get false only if all users have Status == 1.`, in your case you `All` will return **true** if all users has status of `1`. You got it backwards.

Comment: Bah, try this instead:  return Users.Any(x => x.Status != 1);

Answer (score 2):

This will return `false` only if **all** users has status `1`. Otherwise - `true`;

```
public book AllInactive
{
     get { return !Users.All(user => user.Status == 1); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool AllInactive
{
    get
    {
        foreach (UserRow ur in Users)
        {
            if (ur.Status != 1) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

That way, as soon as one user status is not 1, true is returned. else false is returned

Comment: ... or if you like LINQ, "return Users.Any(x => x.Status != 1)"

Comment: `<>`means "not equal". It is the opposite of `==`

Comment: Ok, I got it, but it's C#, not VB :)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I had only read the asp-tags on the question and assumed asp syntax was required. My bad.